# Publishing workflow fails

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, publishing, office-365

Does anyone know what's the problem with a workflow (or sharepoint itself) if I cannot publish a workflow. If I check for errors I get a message that no errors are found and saving the workflow works. But even with the simpelest workflow I cannot publish it (for example with one action: Log to the History list or setting a workflow variable)

If the problem is in sharepoint, is it possible to fix in Office 365? (so without web.config,...)

The error:

> Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were
>   saved but cannot be run.

.. and as advanced message in this error:

> Could not publish the workflow because the workflow configuration file
>   contains errors.

Comment: So is SPD workflow. Don't you have anything in RED showing? Try searching next to the location where you've changed.
..and NO, Office 365 would not help at all as long as your workflow has issues.

Comment: Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: I personally suspect changes in Worflow (e.g. occasionally depending on the type of change in the OOTB Approval workflow you get errors related to the Duration choice field )

Comment: Which version of SP are you using? Foundation/Standard/Enterprise? 2007/2010?

Comment: I tried it in office 365: sharepoint online, but maybe Patrick_J had it somewhere else? (he put bounty on this question)

Comment: I don't think it's a permission issue, i'm site collection admin

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Unable to identify the cause of this issue. Can someone help me out will be highly appreciated in advance. I tried with creating another custom List and only one line in WF (log message), but getting the same issue. As  using Office365 don't have Config file to alter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be with the SharePoint installation itself. If you cannot publish a workflow on any of the web applications in the farm, I think the best way is to reinstall OS and Sharepoint.

Otherwise, You can also try below :

1. Create and publish a workflow associated to a list on another SharePoint farm if you
   have.
2. Open the site(where workflow is published successfully) in designer
   and Go to All Files>Workflows>[YourWorkFlowName] folder.
3. Copy (all three files the folder in Step2) and Replace them at the SharePoint site(where
   you have problem) at All Files>Workflows>[YourWorkFlowName] folder.
4. Replace the guids,Id and description with the actual in  the new .xoml.wfconfig.xml (which you copied) in the `<Template>` and `<Association>` Tags . For  this you can back up below information before replacing .xoml.wfconfig.xml.

   Template BaseID="{EA36B899-39E1-4222-B9CE-88341E9A3898}" DocLibID="{48F49FA8-E7DB-4D5E-B248-9CC24BC8BAFA}" TaskContentType="0x01080100C9C9515DE4E24001905074F980F93160" Category="List" Name="Workflow 1" Description="" XomlHref="Workflows/Workflow 1/Workflow 1.xoml" XomlVersion="V1.0"/>

   Association ListID="{213B5516-238B-45B3-AC17-A68CDC0A3A96}" TaskListID="{CAFDFF34-A25C-4300-BC04-9FF7C319B8BD}" StartManually="true"/>
5. Now try to save the workflow and publish

Answer (score 0):

Another way I just stumbled upon to fix this is to copy and paste all the files within SharePoint Designer (it will call it "Your workflow Name Copy 1")

Then use the copy

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turns out that there were too many previous workflows on the list itself.  I removed most of the old workflows which were instances of the same workflow I was attempting to publish.  I ran the publish afterward removing most of the previous instances with success.